# gdb remote debugging fails strangely

Tags: linux, eclipse, debugging, gdb

I am debugging a x86-64 device using Eclipse with gdb.

It was working fine till yesterday, when I cleaned my project and built it again. Now, I face a strange problem. It starts, and **hits my first breakpoint**. Then, I click `Resume` and it **may** run till my next breakpoint or give a **remote failure reply e7295** error.

On the console I see these annoying lines:

```
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
warning: unrecognized item "timeout" in "qSupported" response
```

My gdb commands are as follows:

```
set architecture i386:x64-32 
set remotebaud 115200
target remote COM1
set disassembly-flavor intel
```

I restarted Eclipse and my laptop, I closed all unnecessary internal windows of Eclipse (memory browser, disassembly etc.), changed my serial cable, debugged the device with the same cable and project on my colleague's laptop.

What may be hindering gdb from debugging?

Comment: Did you update gdb, gdbserver or kernel being debugged? Also take a look at this: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.debugging/1956.

Comment: Try rebooting device as well. I've seen that error when the device has a lingering gdbserver running.