# Use gdb conditionals (if, while) to test (gdb) command success

Tags: gdb

Is it possible to use gdb's `if` or `while` conditionals to test gdb command success (rather than querying a program value or variable)?

Now for clarity I'm talking about gdb built-in commands (ie things that come up when you type `help` in gdb - not the command-under test.

In particular I have a remote target with heavy timing issues where the `gdbserver` sometimes fails to start when the system is under high-load and I'd like to repeat the command until it succeeds.  Something like:

```
while ! target extended-remote | ssh -T target gdbserver --once  - ./binary args
   print "Again"
end
```

Alternatively is there a way to get `gdb` command success into a variable that can be used as a condition - eg in bash it would be `$?`.  Something like:

```
target extended-remote | ssh -T target gdbserver --once  - ./binary args
if <last command failed> 
      # handle failure
end
```

Comment: For context the failure is similar to what is seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373239/

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this using just the gdb CLI.  This is one of the many deficiencies of the CLI as a language.

However, it's relatively easy to do from Python, using gdb's Python scripting capabilities.  One way to do this would be to extend the [`ignore-errors`](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=archer.git;a=blob;f=gdb/python/lib/gdb/command/ignore_errors.py;h=6fa48ff0816fa5945704dcc5535d99d50a29f767) command to also set some convenience variable that you could then test.